# Bootstrap - how to make vertical sidebar with fixed width/not scrollable but still responsive?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am new to bootstrap and trying to figure out how i could:

1. Have a vertical sidebar with fixed width, that doesnt scroll with content but still responsive(if the screen width is too small, it become a top bar with hamburger menu like we are used to)
2. Have the main content div take 100% of remaining width(minus the sidebar fixed width)

Here is what i have so far(codes that i found somewhere that almost accomplish what i want, however the sidebar scroll with the content and content div doesnt take 100% remamining width):

**IMPORTS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function () {
            $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  padding-top: 51px;  
}
.text-center {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.col-xs-12 {
  background-color: #fff;
}
#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
#sidebar .nav {
  width: 95%;
}
#sidebar li {
  border:0 #f2f2f2 solid;
  border-bottom-width:1px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  }
  .row-offcanvas-right
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    right: -41.6%;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    left: -41.6%;
  }
  .row-offcanvas-right.active {
    right: 41.6%;
  }
  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 41.6%;
  }
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 41.6%;
  }
  #sidebar {
    padding-top:0;
  }
}

.fixed {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
    <body>
    <div class="page-container">

        <!-- top navbar -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".sidebar-nav">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project Name</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">

                <!-- sidebar -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas fixed" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <!-- main area -->
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9" style="background-color: blue;">
                    <h1>Shrink Width to Collapse Sidebar</h1>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in nisi eu arcu tempus vehicula.
                        Nulla faucibus cursus metus in sagittis. Nunc elit leo, imperdiet in ligula in, euismod varius est.
                        Aenean pellentesque lorem a porttitor placerat. Vestibulum placerat nunc ac rutrum fringilla. Donec
                        arcu leo, tempus adipiscing volutpat id, congue in purus. Pellentesque scelerisque mattis nibh vel
                        semper. Sed a risus purus. Fusce pulvinar, velit eget rhoncus facilisis, enim elit vulputate nisl, a
                        euismod diam metus eu enim. Nullam congue justo vitae justo accumsan, sit amet malesuada nulla sagittis.
                        Nam neque tellus, tristique in est vel, sagittis congue turpis. Aliquam nulla lacus, laoreet dapibus
                        odio vitae, posuere volutpat magna. Nam pulvinar lacus in sapien feugiat, sit amet vestibulum enim
                        eleifend. Integer sit amet ante auctor, lacinia sem quis, consectetur nulla.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in nisi eu arcu tempus vehicula.
                        Nulla faucibus cursus metus in sagittis. Nunc elit leo, imperdiet in ligula in, euismod varius est.
                        Aenean pellentesque lorem a porttitor placerat. Vestibulum placerat nunc ac rutrum fringilla. Donec
                        arcu leo, tempus adipiscing volutpat id, congue in purus. Pellentesque scelerisque mattis nibh vel
                        semper. Sed a risus purus. Fusce pulvinar, velit eget rhoncus facilisis, enim elit vulputate nisl, a
                        euismod diam metus eu enim. Nullam congue justo vitae justo accumsan, sit amet malesuada nulla sagittis.
                        Nam neque tellus, tristique in est vel, sagittis congue turpis. Aliquam nulla lacus, laoreet dapibus
                        odio vitae, posuere volutpat magna. Nam pulvinar lacus in sapien feugiat, sit amet vestibulum enim
                        eleifend. Integer sit amet ante auctor, lacinia sem quis, consectetur nulla.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in nisi eu arcu tempus vehicula.
                        Nulla faucibus cursus metus in sagittis. Nunc elit leo, imperdiet in ligula in, euismod varius est.
                        Aenean pellentesque lorem a porttitor placerat. Vestibulum placerat nunc ac rutrum fringilla. Donec
                        arcu leo, tempus adipiscing volutpat id, congue in purus. Pellentesque scelerisque mattis nibh vel
                        semper. Sed a risus purus. Fusce pulvinar, velit eget rhoncus facilisis, enim elit vulputate nisl, a
                        euismod diam metus eu enim. Nullam congue justo vitae justo accumsan, sit amet malesuada nulla sagittis.
                        Nam neque tellus, tristique in est vel, sagittis congue turpis. Aliquam nulla lacus, laoreet dapibus
                        odio vitae, posuere volutpat magna. Nam pulvinar lacus in sapien feugiat, sit amet vestibulum enim
                        eleifend. Integer sit amet ante auctor, lacinia sem quis, consectetur nulla.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in nisi eu arcu tempus vehicula.
                        Nulla faucibus cursus metus in sagittis. Nunc elit leo, imperdiet in ligula in, euismod varius est.
                        Aenean pellentesque lorem a porttitor placerat. Vestibulum placerat nunc ac rutrum fringilla. Donec
                        arcu leo, tempus adipiscing volutpat id, congue in purus. Pellentesque scelerisque mattis nibh vel
                        semper. Sed a risus purus. Fusce pulvinar, velit eget rhoncus facilisis, enim elit vulputate nisl, a
                        euismod diam metus eu enim. Nullam congue justo vitae justo accumsan, sit amet malesuada nulla sagittis.
                        Nam neque tellus, tristique in est vel, sagittis congue turpis. Aliquam nulla lacus, laoreet dapibus
                        odio vitae, posuere volutpat magna. Nam pulvinar lacus in sapien feugiat, sit amet vestibulum enim
                        eleifend. Integer sit amet ante auctor, lacinia sem quis, consectetur nulla.
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        Vestibulum porttitor massa eget pellentesque eleifend. Suspendisse tempor, nisi eu placerat auctor,
                        est erat tempus neque, pellentesque venenatis eros lorem vel quam. Nulla luctus malesuada porttitor.
                        Fusce risus mi, luctus scelerisque hendrerit feugiat, volutpat gravida nisi. Quisque facilisis risus
                        in lacus sagittis malesuada. Suspendisse non purus diam. Nunc commodo felis sit amet tortor
                        adipiscing varius. Fusce commodo nulla quis fermentum hendrerit. Donec vulputate, tellus sed
                        venenatis sodales, purus nibh ullamcorper quam, sit amet tristique justo velit molestie lorem.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Vestibulum porttitor massa eget pellentesque eleifend. Suspendisse tempor, nisi eu placerat auctor,
                        est erat tempus neque, pellentesque venenatis eros lorem vel quam. Nulla luctus malesuada porttitor.
                        Fusce risus mi, luctus scelerisque hendrerit feugiat, volutpat gravida nisi. Quisque facilisis risus
                        in lacus sagittis malesuada. Suspendisse non purus diam. Nunc commodo felis sit amet tortor
                        adipiscing varius. Fusce commodo nulla quis fermentum hendrerit. Donec vulputate, tellus sed
                        venenatis sodales, purus nibh ullamcorper quam, sit amet tristique justo velit molestie lorem.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Vestibulum porttitor massa eget pellentesque eleifend. Suspendisse tempor, nisi eu placerat auctor,
                        est erat tempus neque, pellentesque venenatis eros lorem vel quam. Nulla luctus malesuada porttitor.
                        Fusce risus mi, luctus scelerisque hendrerit feugiat, volutpat gravida nisi. Quisque facilisis risus
                        in lacus sagittis malesuada. Suspendisse non purus diam. Nunc commodo felis sit amet tortor
                        adipiscing varius. Fusce commodo nulla quis fermentum hendrerit. Donec vulputate, tellus sed
                        venenatis sodales, purus nibh ullamcorper quam, sit amet tristique justo velit molestie lorem.
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        Fusce sollicitudin lacus lacinia mi tincidunt ullamcorper. Aenean velit ipsum, vestibulum nec
                        tincidunt eu, lobortis vitae erat. Nullam ultricies fringilla ultricies. Sed euismod nibh quis
                        tincidunt dapibus. Nulla quam velit, porta sit amet felis eu, auctor fringilla elit. Donec
                        convallis tincidunt nibh, quis pellentesque sapien condimentum a. Phasellus purus dui, rhoncus
                        id suscipit id, ornare et sem. Duis aliquet posuere arcu a ornare. Pellentesque consequat libero
                        id massa accumsan volutpat. Fusce a hendrerit lacus. Nam elementum ac eros eu porttitor.
                        Phasellus enim mi, auctor sit amet luctus a, commodo fermentum arcu. In volutpat scelerisque
                        quam, nec lacinia libero.
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        Aliquam a lacinia orci, iaculis porttitor neque. Nullam cursus dolor tempus mauris posuere, eu
                        scelerisque sem tincidunt. Praesent blandit sapien at sem pulvinar, vel egestas orci varius.
                        Praesent vitae purus at ante aliquet luctus vel quis nibh. Mauris id nulla vitae est lacinia
                        rhoncus a vel justo. Donec iaculis quis sapien vel molestie. Aliquam sed elementum orci.
                        Vestibulum tristique tempor risus et malesuada. Sed eget ligula sed quam placerat dapibus.
                        Integer accumsan ac massa at tempus.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Vestibulum porttitor massa eget pellentesque eleifend. Suspendisse tempor, nisi eu placerat auctor,
                        est erat tempus neque, pellentesque venenatis eros lorem vel quam. Nulla luctus malesuada porttitor.
                        Fusce risus mi, luctus scelerisque hendrerit feugiat, volutpat gravida nisi. Quisque facilisis risus
                        in lacus sagittis malesuada. Suspendisse non purus diam. Nunc commodo felis sit amet tortor
                        adipiscing varius. Fusce commodo nulla quis fermentum hendrerit. Donec vulputate, tellus sed
                        venenatis sodales, purus nibh ullamcorper quam, sit amet tristique justo velit molestie lorem.
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        Fusce sollicitudin lacus lacinia mi tincidunt ullamcorper. Aenean velit ipsum, vestibulum nec
                        tincidunt eu, lobortis vitae erat. Nullam ultricies fringilla ultricies. Sed euismod nibh quis
                        tincidunt dapibus. Nulla quam velit, porta sit amet felis eu, auctor fringilla elit. Donec
                        convallis tincidunt nibh, quis pellentesque sapien condimentum a. Phasellus purus dui, rhoncus
                        id suscipit id, ornare et sem. Duis aliquet posuere arcu a ornare. Pellentesque consequat libero
                        id massa accumsan volutpat. Fusce a hendrerit lacus. Nam elementum ac eros eu porttitor.
                        Phasellus enim mi, auctor sit amet luctus a, commodo fermentum arcu. In volutpat scelerisque
                        quam, nec lacinia libero.
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        Aliquam a lacinia orci, iaculis porttitor neque. Nullam cursus dolor tempus mauris posuere, eu
                        scelerisque sem tincidunt. Praesent blandit sapien at sem pulvinar, vel egestas orci varius.
                        Praesent vitae purus at ante aliquet luctus vel quis nibh. Mauris id nulla vitae est lacinia
                        rhoncus a vel justo. Donec iaculis quis sapien vel molestie. Aliquam sed elementum orci.
                        Vestibulum tristique tempor risus et malesuada. Sed eget ligula sed quam placerat dapibus.
                        Integer accumsan ac massa at tempus.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Vestibulum porttitor massa eget pellentesque eleifend. Suspendisse tempor, nisi eu placerat auctor,
                        est erat tempus neque, pellentesque venenatis eros lorem vel quam. Nulla luctus malesuada porttitor.
                        Fusce risus mi, luctus scelerisque hendrerit feugiat, volutpat gravida nisi. Quisque facilisis risus
                        in lacus sagittis malesuada. Suspendisse non purus diam. Nunc commodo felis sit amet tortor
                        adipiscing varius. Fusce commodo nulla quis fermentum hendrerit. Donec vulputate, tellus sed
                        venenatis sodales, purus nibh ullamcorper quam, sit amet tristique justo velit molestie lorem.
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        Fusce sollicitudin lacus lacinia mi tincidunt ullamcorper. Aenean velit ipsum, vestibulum nec
                        tincidunt eu, lobortis vitae erat. Nullam ultricies fringilla ultricies. Sed euismod nibh quis
                        tincidunt dapibus. Nulla quam velit, porta sit amet felis eu, auctor fringilla elit. Donec
                        convallis tincidunt nibh, quis pellentesque sapien condimentum a. Phasellus purus dui, rhoncus
                        id suscipit id, ornare et sem. Duis aliquet posuere arcu a ornare. Pellentesque consequat libero
                        id massa accumsan volutpat. Fusce a hendrerit lacus. Nam elementum ac eros eu porttitor.
                        Phasellus enim mi, auctor sit amet luctus a, commodo fermentum arcu. In volutpat scelerisque
                        quam, nec lacinia libero.
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        Aliquam a lacinia orci, iaculis porttitor neque. Nullam cursus dolor tempus mauris posuere, eu
                        scelerisque sem tincidunt. Praesent blandit sapien at sem pulvinar, vel egestas orci varius.
                        Praesent vitae purus at ante aliquet luctus vel quis nibh. Mauris id nulla vitae est lacinia
                        rhoncus a vel justo. Donec iaculis quis sapien vel molestie. Aliquam sed elementum orci.
                        Vestibulum tristique tempor risus et malesuada. Sed eget ligula sed quam placerat dapibus.
                        Integer accumsan ac massa at tempus.
                    </p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want the side bar to always been on display, even when your scroll?, and as far as I can see the content does take up 100% of the page width.

Comment: I want the side bar to always be on display even when we scroll the content, and yes the content actually doesn't take all the remaining width minus the sidebar width(but I want it to do).

Answer (score 0):

I have it working so that the menu is stuck to the left the content is 100% of the rest of the pages width. To do this;

**Sidebar Postion Fixed**

**Step One**

Change - `<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas fixed" id="sidebar" role="navigation">` to - `<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas fixedSide" id="sidebar" role="navigation">`

**Step Two**

Add the following to your CSS at the bottom of your CSS -

```
 .fixedSide {
    position: fixed;
    top: 75px;    
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

**Step 3**

Remove the following from your current CSS;

```
.fixed {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

**Content 100%**

**Step 1**

Add `content fix` class to `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9" style="background-color: blue;">`

**Step 2**

Add the following CSS;

```
.contentfix {
    margin-left: 20%; 
    width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .contentfix {
    margin-left: 0%;   
 }

}
```

Comment: Sorry didn't see you found a solution, hope you get it all working :)